# Log4J2 Yaml Package Levels

Tags: java, logging, yaml, package, log4j2

I am trying to get my logging using log4j2 and yaml working and have been struggling.

The package com.eclipse is very noisy so I want to only log messages from that package at warn or above.  For my packages I want to log a debug and above to the rolling appender and error or above to the error log. On the console I want to see debug for everything but org.ecplise

With my current config, I don't see the org.eclipse debug messages which is good and I see the com.myorganization messages on the console but the file appenders don't seem to be working.  If I change the order of the last two loggers then the org.eclipse messages come back to the console but the file appenders for my package start working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my current config:

```
Configuration:
  name: Default

  Properties:
    Property:
      name: log-path
      value: "logs"

  Appenders:

    Console:
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
      name: Console
      target: SYSTEM_OUT

    File:
      name: File_Appender
      fileName: ${log-path}/minimal-ws.error.log
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'

    RollingFile:
      - name: RollingFile_Appender
        fileName: ${log-path}/minimal-ws.log
        filePattern: 'logs/archive/minimal-ws.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz'
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
        Policies:
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 10 MB
        DefaultRollOverStrategy:
          max: 10

  Loggers:

    Root:
      AppenderRef:
      - ref: Console
      level: DEBUG

    Logger:
      - name: com.myorganization
        level: DEBUG
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: File_Appender
            level: ERROR
          - ref: RollingFile_Appender
            level: DEBUG

    Logger:
      - name: org.eclipse
        level: DEBUG
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
        - ref: Console
          level: WARN
```

Comment: You have indentation issues on this file, not sure if it is due to the copy/paste or not. Can you check `level: DEBUG` on the Root Logger and `- ref: Console` on the `org.eclipse` Logger, they both need to be one tab to the right

Answer (score 1):

You don't need define multiple `Logger:` definition in `yaml`. Instead have a single `Logger:` definition with multiple `- name:` attributes. Following is the working solution as per your requirement. [Please change the package names accordingly.]

```
Configuration:
  name: Default

  Properties:
    Property:
      name: log-path
      value: "."

  Appenders:

    Console:
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
      name: Console
      target: SYSTEM_OUT

    File:
      name: File_Appender
      fileName: ${log-path}/minimal-ws.error.log
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'

    RollingFile:
      - name: RollingFile_Appender
        fileName: ${log-path}/minimal-ws.log
        filePattern: 'logs/archive/minimal-ws.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz'
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
        Policies:
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 10 MB
        DefaultRollOverStrategy:
          max: 10

  Loggers:
    Root:
      AppenderRef:
      - ref: Console
        level: ERROR

    Logger:
      - name: eclipse
        level: DEBUG
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
        - ref: Console
          level: DEBUG
        - ref: File_Appender
          level: DEBUG
      - name: com
        level: DEBUG
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: Console
            level: INFO
          - ref: File_Appender
            level: ERROR
          - ref: RollingFile_Appender
            level: DEBUG
```

This configuration writes in `Console`, `File_Appender` and `RollingFile_Appender`